# Only print terminal directories in "du"?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, du

Is there a generalized solution for getting only the deepest directories?  Counting slash characters won't work, because if I change to `--max-depth=4`, the deepest directories won't all have the same number of slashes.

The two directories indicated by `<<<<` are the ones I want.

```
-bash-4.1$ du --max-depth=3 -h /Database/9.6/backups > x.x
du: cannot read directory `/Database/9.6/backups/lost+found': Permission denied
-bash-4.1$ cat x.x
16K     /Database/9.6/backups/lost+found
142G    /Database/9.6/backups/pgbackrest/archive/localhost  <<<<
142G    /Database/9.6/backups/pgbackrest/archive
4.9T    /Database/9.6/backups/pgbackrest/backup/localhost   <<<<
4.9T    /Database/9.6/backups/pgbackrest/backup
5.0T    /Database/9.6/backups/pgbackrest
5.0T    /Database/9.6/backups
```

Comment: Please define "deepest". Is it "locally deepest"? I guess not. E.g. in your example `lost+found` is locally deepest (it has no subdirectories) but you don't want it. So do you want "globally deepest"? In your example `lost+found` is not globally deepest because its depth is less than some other depth *in the entire directory tree* in question. This makes sense, but please confirm. If you want "globally deepest", is the depth of the deepest known in advance?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the subject line says "Only print **terminal** directories", and that's what I want: to only print the terminal directories, when limited by `--max-depth=3`.

Comment: So "directories of certain depth" and the depth is known in advance. Right?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes, depth is known in advance.  That’s demonstrated by use of the `—max-depth` option in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered locating the directories with `find`?
It has both `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` :)

```
$ du -h -cs $(find -maxdepth 4 -mindepth 4 -type d)
4.0K    ./ackups/pgbackrest/backup/localhost
4.0K    ./backups/pgbackrest/archive/localhost
8.0K    total
```

Comment: That worked.  The only change I I had to make was to add `2> /dev/null`.

Comment: The unquoted `$(find …)` will break the solution if pathnames contain spaces and/or other "troublesome" characters. The best fix is `find … -print0 | du --files0-from - …`. The OP's tools may or may not support these options.

Comment: @RonJohn if my answer workes for you, consider marking it as the accepted one :)

Comment: @criztovyl I try and wait 24 hours to see if other answers arrive.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski good point.  The files in that directory have a known naming format, so is not relevant to my current situation.

Comment: @RonJohn then I was just impatient, nvm!